# Uploadfile method to overwrite file on webserver

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

What I am trying to do is create a small "shoutbox" where everyone will have a log on their computer that'll store everything that is typed over a textbox and upload it on a file that is located on a **webserver**. What I want it to do now is to overwrite existing content inside the file when file already exists.
The webserver is local.

What I've tried so far:

```
 Private Sub sendmsg_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sendmsg.Click
        Try
            Dim path As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\chatlog.txt"
            Dim writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path, True)
            Dim address As String = "http://localhost/tonakis2108/shoutbox.txt"

            'Grabs text from textboxes and hides logfile
            writer.WriteLine(nickname.Text + ": " + msg.Text)
            writer.Close()
            File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Hidden) 'Hides file

            'Uploads file
            My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(path, address, "", "", True, 50)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

The problem:

The problem I face is when I change or delete the file on the server I get an error 404 that the destination doesn't exist and when the file is already there and empty it doesn't do anything when I upload.

Comment: You need server-side code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to adirection however I am not acquainted with that kind of coding and I don't know where to start.